# Running Dojo on RequireJS

Tags: dojo, requirejs

I am using Dojo 1.9.1 and RequireJS

I implemented it using this code:

```
 <script src="require.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '/js/',  // magic!
        packages: [
          {
            name: 'dojo',
            location: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/"
          }
        ]
     }); 
 </script>
```

...
..

```
<script>
      require(["dojo/domReady!"], function() { 
       ......
      });
    </script>
```

it will throw some exceptions about has.js not work correctly

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){} has no method 'add' has.js:8
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: dojo/domReady!_unnormalized2
```

Does any one have an explanation, or an idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using both Dojo and RequireJS, and not simply using Dojo's `require` and `define`?

Comment: I have an existing backbone app that uses requirejs and i want to integrate ArcGis Map (javascript API working with Dojo https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jstutorials/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CDN version of Dojo is built assuming that you are using the Dojo loader in order to decrease code size. Part of the code removal is the alternative has.js implementation that is used if a loader doesn’t include one (like RequireJS). You can use a regular downloaded version of Dojo with RequireJS and it will work fine, but you can’t use the CDN version.